# base js: how to add a property to an object in the 'old' way?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, javascript-objects

This line causes ie11 to cry.

```
return {...item, distanza: distance_from_user / 1000}
```

> All of us hate ie11, but our customer no.. so be patient

ie11 do not knows *destructuring*.

Here `item` is a js object, a *plain* js object, there is no jQuery or similar involved. It's coming from an ajax-loaded json.

I simply but add a field namd 'distanza' to `item` before returning.

What the oldest working method?

Comment: You would have to manually set each value of item sadly

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by genbs for using the polyfill mentioned in this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). It can help you to assign properties to object for IE 11 browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved using banally the dot notation.

Having an `item` var in js, that is a plain old js object, I simply add a field using

```
item.new_field = <data to add>
```

and it simply works.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const copied = Object.assign({}, item, { distanza: distance_from_user / 1000})
```

or

```
const copied = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item))

copied.distanza = distance_from_user / 1000
```

Comment: Sorry, but Object.assign is NOT WORKING on ie11 - https://caniuse.com/?search=Object.assign

Comment: At the bottom of the page link  you can see the polyfill for old browsers